# Probability Of Rolling 2 Identical Numbers In 3 Rolls

Tags: probability, dice

A single fair die is rolled 3 times.

What is the probability of rolling exactly two identical numbers?

I've done the working for if a die is rolled 2 times:
There's a 1/6 * 1/6 chance of getting the same number. Then there are 6 different pairs of numbers (1,1) (2,2) etc. This gives a 1/6 chance of getting the same number.

However when another roll is added, obviously the chances would go up, but im getting stuck on how the 1st and 3rd roll could be the same, and then you would need to equate those instances. Sorry if I'm unclear!

Thanks for simplifying the question to:
Possible outcome of same numbers being:

1 of the same number, +

2 of the same number, +

3 of the same number,

and then just subtract 1 and 3.

Comment: What would be the probability of two identical numbers with 2 rolls? Maybe you can build from there.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the probability they're all equal? ($6$ times ${\frac{1}{6}}^3$, why?)

What's the probability the three throws are all distinct? ($\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{4}{6}$ do you see why?)

What remains is the probability you're looking for: the three throws have outcome set of size $1,2$ or $3$...

Comment: I get $1 - \frac{1}{36} - \frac{20}{36} = \frac{36}{36} - \frac{21}{36} = \frac{15}{36} = \frac{5}{12}$

Answer (score 0):

There are ${3\choose 2}\cdot 5$ ways to get exactly two $1$s: e.g.: $\underbrace{11\bar{1}}_{5}, \underbrace{1\bar{1}1}_{5},\underbrace{\bar{1}11}_{5}$.

There are $6$ numbers, so: ${3\choose 2}\cdot 5\cdot 6=90$ ways to get exactly two identical numbers.

There are total $6^3=216$ different outcomes.

Hence:
$$P(\text{2 same numbers in 3 rolls})=\frac{90}{216}=\frac5{12}.$$